# Suppressing blankspace in input through scanf

Tags: c, stdio

To suppress newline we use %[^\n]. Can you suggest what should be the format to skip blank in the input, i.e. if we have to input "hallo stackflow". I know fgets and gets but i don't want to use them, they are creating problem.

Comment: You must be clearer. What kind of problems do they create? If you want non-blocking input, say so.

Comment: fgets is waiting for ever.even after new line it is not receving the line.i know it reads every thing untill eof or newline .am using this in a chatting programme in client-server.on server side it is reciving quit as expected but on the client side it has got blocked.

Comment: Could you post some code? Maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a blank in the [scanf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf) format; that suppresses whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "include whitespace". Use:

```
#define str(x) #x
#define xstr(x) str(x)
/* ... */
char buf[ SIZE + 1 ] = "";
int rc = scanf("%" xstr(SIZE) "[^\n]%*[^\n]", buf);
/*you may need the return value later on, if reading
  in multiple strings with whitespaces in a loop */
if (!feof(stdin)) 
     getchar(); /* consume newline */
```